# How do I create a new column if the text from one column if the text from a second column contains a specific string pattern?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

My current data looks something like this

```
+-------+----------------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
| Index |             0              |         1         |           2           |
+-------+----------------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
|     0 | Reference Curr             | Daybook / Voucher | Invoice Date Due Date |
|     1 | V50011 Tech Comp           | nan               | Phone:0177222222      |
|     2 | Regis Place                | nan               | Fax:017757575789      |
|     3 | Catenberry                 | nan               | nan                   |
|     4 | Manhattan, NY              | nan               | nan                   |
|     5 | V7484 Pipe                 | nan               | Phone:                   |
|     6 | Japan                      | nan               | nan                   |
|     7 | nan                        | nan               | nan                   |
|     8 | 4543.34GBP (British Pound) | nan               | nan                   |
+-------+----------------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
```

I am trying to create a new column, `df['Company']`, that should contain the what is in `df[0]` if it Starts with a "V" and if `df[2]` has "Phone" in it. If the condition is not satisfied, then it can be `nan`. Below is what I am looking for.

```
+-------+----------------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+------------+
| Index |             0              |         1         |           2           | Company    |
+-------+----------------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+------------+
|     0 | Reference Curr             | Daybook / Voucher | Invoice Date Due Date | nan        |
|     1 | V50011 Tech                | nan               | Phone:0177222222      |V50011 Tech |
|     2 | Regis Place                | nan               | Fax:017757575789      | nan        |
|     3 | Catenberry                 | nan               | nan                   | nan        |
|     4 | Manhattan, NY              | nan               | nan                   | nan        |
|     5 | V7484 Pipe                 | nan               | Phone:                | V7484 Pipe |
|     6 | Japan                      | nan               | nan                   | nan        |
|     7 | nan                        | nan               | nan                   | nan        |
|     8 | 4543.34GBP (British Pound) | nan               | nan                   | nan        |
+-------+----------------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+------------+
```

I am trying the below script but I get an error `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 1420`, placement implies 1

```py
df['Company'] = pd.np.where(df[2].str.contains("Ph"), df[0].str.extract(r"(^V[A-Za-z0-9]+)"),"stop")
```

I put in "stop" as the else part because I don't know how to let python use `nan` when the condition is not met.

I would also like to be able to parse out a section of the df[0], for example just the v5001 section, but not rest of the cell contents. I tried something like this using AMCs answer but get an error:

```py
df.loc[df[0].str.startswith('V') & df[2].str.contains('Phone'), 'Company'] = df[0].str.extract(r"(^V[A-Za-z0-9]+)")
```

Thank you

Comment: I don't think you even need to use `where()` here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't provided an easy way for us to test potential solutions, but this should do the job:

```py
df.loc[df[0].str.startswith('V') & df[2].str.contains('Phone'), 'Company'] = df[0]
```

Comment: thank you. If I would want to parse out a section of the df[0], for example just the v5001 section, but not the part after it, is that possible?
Something like this
df.loc[df[0].str.startswith('V') & df[2].str.contains('Phone'), 'Company'] = df[0].str.extract(r"(^V[A-Za-z0-9]+)")

Comment: _If I would want to parse out a section of the df[0], for example just the v5001 section, but not the part after it, is that possible?_ Sure, yeah, as long as you can write a regex for it or something. That code looks like it should work.

Comment: Please add this to your question rather than as a comment

Comment: @LeoE I added it, thank you. I still get an error "ValueError: Incompatible indexer with DataFrame" when I try the adjusted solution to use RegEx... not sure why

Comment: @Shmelky What does the result of `df[0].str.extract(r"(^V[A-Za-z0-9]+)")` look like?

Comment: @AMC if I run df['test'] = df[0].str.extract(r"(^V[A-Za-z0-9]+)")
I will get that new column with V50011 for Index row 1 and V7484 for Index row 5 and the rest nan. When I run that as part of your solution, I get the incompatible error.
The reason I have the "Phone" condition is that sometimes the df[0] starts with a "V" but it is not the data I want so "Phone" in df[2] helps make sure that it only will grab the desired data that has "V" in the beginning.

Comment: @Shmelky I meant what is the output of just `df[0].str.extract(r"(^V[A-Za-z0-9]+)")`. My guess is that you should include the `expand=False` argument to `.extract()`.

Comment: @AMC sorry about that. If I just run it alone, I get
           0
0        NaN
1     V50011
2        NaN
3        NaN
4        NaN
...

Comment: @Shmelky Try using `.to_list()` on the result of the extract when you’re assigning, that should work.

Comment: @AMC so I added expand=False and that seemed to do the trick. Thank you for your time and patience!

Comment: @Shmelky You're welcome! Remember that you can accept my answer if it did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

A potential solution to this would be to use list comprehension.  You could probably get a speed boost using some of pandas' built in functions but this will get you there.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    0:["reference", "v5001 tech comp", "catenberry", "very different"],
    1:["not", "phone", "other", "text"]
    })

df["new_column"] = [x  if (x[0].lower() == "v") & ("phone" in y.lower())
  else np.nan for x,y in df.loc[:, [0,1]].values]

print(df)
```

Which will produce

```
                 0      1       new_column
0        reference    not              NaN
1  v5001 tech comp  phone  v5001 tech comp
2       catenberry  other              NaN
3   very different   text              NaN
```

All I'm doing is taking your two conditions and building a new list which will then be assigned to your new column.

Comment: I think _It's very pythonic_ is somewhat debatable.

Comment: @AMC removed to avoid debate.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to get your result

```
condition1=df['0'].str.startswith('V')
condition2=df['2'].str.contains('Phone')

df['Company']=np.where((condition1 & condition2), df['0'],np.nan)
df['Company']=df['Company'].str.split(' ',expand=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the pandas `apply` function:

```
import re
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df['Company'] = df.apply(lambda x: x[0].split()[0] if re.match(r'^v[A-Za-z0-9]+', x[0].lower()) and 'phone' in x[1].lower() else np.nan, axis=1)
```

## Edit:

To adjust to comment under @AMC's answer

Comment: i didn't vote on it, but I think AMC's approach is cleaner and more... pandas-onic? i prefer using the built-in pandas filtering rather than doing that in a lambda.

Comment: I get that, but this should not mean a downvote, my answer correctly does the job OP asked for and is valid... Thanks for the response though

Comment: _my answer correctly does the job OP asked for and is valid..._ Not all solutions which produce the correct output are equal though, right?

Comment: This is why you should get more upvotes. Downvotes however mean (at least for me) that there is something wrong with the answer. But this apparently has lead to a lot of discussion, see for example https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130046/when-should-i-vote

Comment: If someone asked how to sum the list of numbers `my_list = [1, 2, 3]`, is the answer `eval('sum(my_list)')` not downvote worthy? It works fine, no?

Comment: To cite from SO help page: "Voting up a question or answer signals to the rest of the community that a post is interesting, well-researched, and useful, while voting down a post signals the opposite: that the post contains wrong information, is poorly researched, or fails to communicate information." I don't think, that my answer falls under the "downvote" category. `eval('sum(my_list)')` however does, since it fails to communicate information, especially about the `eval(...)` part. Anyway, all I hope for is an explanation if downvoted ;)

Comment: @LeoE _since it fails to communicate information_ What information does it fail to communicate?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206081/discussion-between-leoe-and-amc).

Answer (score 0):

IIUC,

we can use either a boolean condition to extract the V Number with some basic regex,

or we can apply the same formula within a where statement.

to set a value to `NaN` we can use `np.nan`

if you want to grab the entire string after V we can use `[V]\w+.*` which will grab everything after the first match.

```
from IO import StringIO

 d = """+-------+----------------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
| Index |             0              |         1         |           2           |
+-------+----------------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
|     0 | Reference Curr             | Daybook / Voucher | Invoice Date Due Date |
|     1 | V50011 Tech Comp           | nan               | Phone:0177222222      |
|     2 | Regis Place                | nan               | Fax:017757575789      |
|     3 | Catenberry                 | nan               | nan                   |
|     4 | Manhattan, NY              | nan               | nan                   |
|     5 | Ultilagro, CT              | nan               | nan                   |
|     6 | Japan                      | nan               | nan                   |
|     7 | nan                        | nan               | nan                   |
|     8 | 4543.34GBP (British Pound) | nan               | nan                   |
+-------+----------------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(d),sep='|',skiprows=1)
df = df.iloc[1:-1,2:-1]
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()

df["3"] = df[df["2"].str.contains("phone", case=False) == True]["0"].str.extract(
    r"([V]\w+)"
)
```

---

```
print(df[['0','2','3']])
                           0                      2       3
1              Reference Curr  Invoice Date Due Date     nan
2            V50011 Tech Comp       Phone:0177222222  V50011
3                 Regis Place       Fax:017757575789     nan
4                  Catenberry                    nan     nan
5               Manhattan, NY                    nan     nan
6               Ultilagro, CT                    nan     nan
7                       Japan                    nan     nan
8                         nan                    nan     nan
9  4543.34GBP (British Pound)                    nan     nan
```

if you want as a where statement:

```
import numpy as np



df["3"] = np.where(
    df[df["2"].str.contains("phone", case=False)], df["0"].str.extract(r"([V]\w+)"), np.nan
)
            print(df[['0','2','3']])
                                   0                      2       3
        1              Reference Curr  Invoice Date Due Date     NaN
        2            V50011 Tech Comp       Phone:0177222222  V50011
        3                 Regis Place       Fax:017757575789     NaN
        4                  Catenberry                    nan     NaN
        5               Manhattan, NY                    nan     NaN
        6               Ultilagro, CT                    nan     NaN
        7                       Japan                    nan     NaN
        8                         nan                    nan     NaN
        9  4543.34GBP (British Pound)                    nan     NaN
```

Comment: Even in a situation where `== True` might make sense, it would be written `is True`. In this case, it's entirely unnecessary.

Comment: @AMC it's more pythonic as it's explicit, if you change it to `False` it will return every index apart from 2.

Comment: _it’s more pythonic as it’s explicit_ Is `if x > 2 == True:` more pythonic than `if x > 2:`? _if you change it to False_ I wouldn’t change it to False, I would use the element wise logical negation operator `~`.

Comment: @AMC that's subjective, and in this case, immaterial.

Comment: It's immaterial?